# Open several CMD programs in one window

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, cmd

FPipe is a program from Mcafee that creates pipes between 2 IPs, when I'm using it I can't use my CMD anymore.

If I do for example `fpipe.exe -l 3389 -r 3389 -v  192.168.8.101` the console doesn't allow me to continue working because FPipe is running so if I want to redirect any other port with that program I have to open a new CMD window and type, for example, `fpipe.exe -l 22002 -r 22 -v  192.168.8.2`

Well, I need to do that 8 times to redirect 8 ports, but I don't want to see 8 CMD windows every time and have to close them 1 by 1. 
Is it possible to have only **one Window** (created in a bat or vbs file) that runs this 8 process at the same time (just 1 CMD or whatever for 8 process) and if I close it... this will end all of this process?

Comment: You know when you type your problem and find the solution 5 mins later? yeah, that happens to me right now!

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer to your own problem so this question shows as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND SOLUTION

I can use this in my batch-file:

call start /b fpipe.exe -l 3389 -r 3389 -v 192.168.8.101

call start /b fpipe.exe -l 22002 -r 22 -v 192.168.8.2

call start /b fpipe.exe -l 22200 -r 22 -v 192.168.8.200